# Is there a best practice for storing ReactJS hooks files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, directory-structure

I've been through the [ReactJS documentation regarding building custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) a few times, but I don't see a convention for where custom hooks should be stored within the project directory.

I'm trying to establish a convention for our developers and am wondering if the larger React community has solved this already.

For example, should they live within any of the following?

`/hooks`

`/components/hooks`

`/utils`

`/use`

My thought is that simply putting them within `/hooks` is best as they aren't really React components. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: React, in everything, leaves the implementation details to the developers. It's then only a matter of opinion and personal preferences. Go with one way, document it, and stick with it.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks @EmileBergeron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically I put ours in a `helpers` folder if it's shared across routes, or directly in the route folder if only needed there.

A flatter directory structure is simpler especially when you can just do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> in VScode to find the file you're looking for.

React isn't opinionated on this, however the man himself has a take on it https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1145354949871767552